# Recent Java upgrade causes TLS handshake failure with elliptic curve server certificate?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, elliptic-curve, sslhandshakeexception

On October 19th, I upgraded to OpenJDK Java 1.8.0_232 and my Java processes started failing to connect to a service fronted by stunnel using an EC server certificate. I have an EC client certificate that I would present to the server if the initial handshake would succeed, but it's not getting that far.

I was unable to obtain the version number of the *previous* version of Java that was running -- I had a long-running process on the client that was able to connect to the service successfully. Java has been upgraded but that client hadn't been restarted since the upgrade. I restarted the client and it, too, began to fail.

I'm about to start reading the [announcement](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2019-October/010452.html) to see if there is anything in there that would suggest a "fix" to something, but I believe I have everything configured correctly on both client and server. My current thinking is that this is a bug in the JVM.

Using [ssltest](https://github.com/ChristopherSchultz/ssltest), I have been able to confirm that I can handshake with the server using multiple cipher suites when providing the correct client certificate, as long as I use Java 1.8.0_181 or Java 11.0.3 (these are the two versions I happened to have laying around on my laptop for testing). Using the same files, command-line, etc. fails when using Java 1.8.0_232.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

**UPDATE**

I have downloaded x86-64 OpenJDK versions 8u222 and 8u232 from [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jdk8u/Main) and I can confirm that version 8u222 will connect and 8u232 will not connect.

**UPDATE**
Downgrading to the previous version of OpenJDK has solved my problem for the time being. I'm using Debian Stretch, and I was able to downgrade with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless=8u222-b10-1~deb9u1 openjdk-8-jre-headless=8u222-b10-1~deb9u1
```

Note that I only have the "headless" packages installed, so I only downgraded the "headless" packages.

**UPDATE**
I can confirm that the client certificate is a red herring, here. I relaxed the requirements on my server to not require the client certificate and the initial TLS handshake still fails. I'm trying to narrow this down to the simplest test case I can get.

**UPDATE**
Still trying to diagnose the problem, here. I have a test server where I can launch it under various configurations and see what happens. I have determined that while Java 8u222 supports the `secp256k1` curve, Java 8u232 does not, and I get the handshake failure.

Comment: Maybe something to do with client & server not having a common key exchange algorithm so that they can negotiate / agree on one to establish connection?

Comment: The `secp256k1` curve has been disabled with jdk 8u232 (see https://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml). It can be reenabled with the java system property `jdk.tls.namedGroups`.

Comment: @SteveHarrington I wrote a client+server that run together in a single process. It runs fine in 8u222 and fails with handshake failure in 8u232. No errors on the server-end of the connection; it just fails on the handshake. I would have expected the server to fail to start with an unsupported key algorithm,.

Comment: @FelixSchumacher Thanks so much for the reference; stupid of me not to see it. I was reading the release announcement which oddly does not mention the mass disabling of a whopping *7* curves. Make that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `secp256k1` curve has been disabled with jdk 8u232 (see https://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml). It can be re-enabled with the java system property `jdk.tls.namedGroups`.

The example on the faq lists a few other *Obsolete NIST EC Curves* that are disabled as well. The curves listed there are `sect283k1`, `sect283r1`, `sect409k1`, `sect409r1`, `sect571k1`, `sect571r1` and `secp256k1`. The system property `jdk.tls.namedGroups` takes a comma separated list of those names.

Comment: I wrote some code to interrogate the `Provider` for what curves are supported, and in both versions the curves say they are supported. Do you have any idea how to find out which curves are actually _enabled_?